# Issue in implementing android app actions via google assistant

Tags: android, android-studio, dialogflow-es, assistant, app-actions

I want to call my apps setting page via google assistant. Or any page from google assistant.
Like " Open Settings in MyDemoApp ", " Create an Object in MyDemoApp ", " Create an Object with price 25$ In MyDemoApp".

I already have deeps links. I tried SliceProvider and somehow it's not working at all. I want to implement App Actions but Dialogflow is too complicated.

I tried creating conversation but I don't want that. I want my app to open via the assistant command directly without any conversation. For example : "Open Main Page in MyDemoApp" , "Open Report Page in MyDemoApp".

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Dialogflow to implement App Actions for your Android app.
What you're looking for is likely this built-in intent that you can leverage:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature

You should be able to map your deep links to the different screens in your app to trigger via the open app feature built-in intent.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started should help you get started.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I already tried this and it isn't working
1. The Test Tool says login to same google account , although I have only one account logged in to studio, phone, and console.
2. The app_feature was broken till Feb but had some improvements in march but not sure how to make it work.
3. My App name is not in English so I tried in another app and still it isn't opening what I want to open. "Open Settings in App Details" - I tried this and it isn't working

Comment: Hi Asif, you mentioned this is not getting triggered via the test tool, we are not aware of any issues that would cause this. Please use the latest Android Studio Plugin 3.3.0. Also, did you update "history" in the test tool UI to your feature name "settings" ? And try with the query "Open testapp settings" where testapp is the name you chose when you created the preview. And  I assume you have already tested your deep link via adb.